# Restored toolbar into Visual studio 2010 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, toolbar

I noticed from the responses I did not see any solution for VS 2010 Express.  So here it is:

View Toolbox, Right click inside toolbox window, click on Show All!

-----I reset the toolbox and all selections went away.  I was thinking refresh but, it did a refresh from dll's and removed the Show All option.

How Can I restored my Toolbar.

Even I don't have Studio command prompt. I search the.*.tbd files in my machine but not found any file for delete.

Comment: I literally have no idea what you are talking about. Is this a solution, a question, what?

Comment: I need help. Now there is no toolbar in my VS2010 express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research I found 
The following steps allow you to reset the Toolbox completely and enable Visual Studio to rebuilt it from scratch. In most cases, this procedure solves all issues related to Silverlight toolbox items.

Above all, reset the Toolbox from Visual Studio. For this right-click the Toolbox and click the "Reset Toolbox" item. After the reset procedure is done, follow these steps:

1. Close Visual Studio;
2. Open the 
   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VCSExpress\10.0
   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0

(Windows 7) folder and remove all the .TBD files;
3. Run the "regedit" tool. For this click the "Run" item in the Start menu and type "regedit" without quotation marks;

1. Find the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VCSExpress\ToolboxControlsInstaller_AssemblyFoldersExCache" and "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VCSExpress\ToolboxControlsInstallerCache" keys;
2. Remove everything from these keys leaving them empty;
3. Run Visual Studio again and wait until it recreates all items in the Toolbox.